# Flattened Tree as an Unrolled Linked List for fast Binary Search

Tags: linked-list, tree, binary-search

I have a tree data structure that I turn into a sorted flat list (an unrolled linked list data structure). Now I want to do a fast binary search and the idea I came up with is: each list element stores a pointer to another element that is the MID child element from the original tree structure. For fast deletion it might be good for each element to point back to its "parent" as well.

Questions:

- Is this already a named data structure? What is its "official" name?
- What is the time complexity O(?) for sorted insertion, deletion and random access by key aka search?

[edit] This is a semi-graphical representation of such a structure:

This tree (written in JSON notation):

```
    {
      "abc": {
        "a": 42,
        "b": 43,
        "c": 44
      },
      "d": 45,
      "e": {
        "f": {
          "g": 46,
          "h": 47
        }
      }
    }
```

is flattened to this list:
(the "-> x" means the element points to the address of element at index x)
(each element stores the key from the original tree and the value, if any)

```
    [0] "abc": nil -> 2
    [1] "a":   42  -> nil
    [2] "b":   43  -> nil
    [3] "c":   44  -> nil
    [4] "d":   45  -> nil
    [5] "e":   nil -> 6
    [6] "f":   nil -> 7
    [7] "g":   46  -> nil
    [8] "h":   47  -> nil
```

legend:

```
    [INDEX] "KEY": VALUE -> ADDRESS OF MID CHILD ELEMENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're thinking about a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data_structure) (or a doubly linked list if you're also linking to the previous element).

About insertion, linked lists have a search time of O(n) and an insert time of O(1), and trees have a search time and access time ranging from O(n) to O(log n) depending on how they are sorted, I'll let you [see for yourself](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

In the end, if you're using a tree with a O(log n) search time, you're better off using it directly, otherwise it depends on how long it takes to turn your tree into a sorted linked list (probably O(n)).

Also, as a bonus, the scientific term reading the "mid" child of a tree is called "in-order traversal", as opposed to pre-order and post-order traversal.

Comment: I learned that each element in a linked list contains a pointer to the next element. What I have is a linked list (rather an unrolled linked list but that does not seem to be relevant here) where an element points to the mid of its child elements (given that the element was formerly part of a tree structure with n child nodes). This structure is different from a normal linked list. Does this have a name?

Comment: As to why I am flattening the original tree structure in the first place: Actually I do not even have the tree but keep the data in the unrolled linked list. I introduced the tree in my question to illustrate the actual semantic structure of the data.

Comment: @kitomer I'm not sure I really get what structure you're talking about (especially how you define the "mid of its child elements"). Can you post an example ? Diagram, class/struct definition, "add" method ?